# Debugging Web Requests on an Android Device

Tags: android, debugging, fiddler

Is there a way to route requests made through the web browser on an Android device through Fiddler? I would like to debug web requests that my device is making when I load a web page, and the equivalent emulator not necessarily giving me the same results.

Thanks,

Dave Morris

Comment: For future searchers...I wrote up steps to use Fiddler to capture HTTP traffic from an Android device (phone or tablet): http://www.cantoni.org/2011/06/28/debug-http-android-fiddler

Answer (score 1):

You can set up the [emulator to run Web requests through a proxy](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#proxy). There are ways for you to set up your own code to use a proxy. I am not aware of a way to have a production device use a proxy for the built-in Web browser, though.

Comment: I was running my web requests on my emulators through a proxy last week, but for some reason, this week, my emulators, all four of them (1.6, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2) are unable to connect to the internet through the web browser. I found a ticket that seems to be related to the issue I'm having, but it says it was fixed a long time ago:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=996

Thanks for your help,
Dave

Comment: @Dave Morris: Are you sure somebody did not change the configuration of the proxy?